# Is every linear functional of L1 the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous linear functionals?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is the following true? For any linear functional $A$ from $L_1(S,\Sigma,\mu)\to\mathbb{R}$ there is a sequence of continuous linear functionals $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ so that for all $f\in L_1(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ , $\lim_{k\to\infty} B_k[f]=A[f]$. Might it help if $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Comment: If $B_k$ are convergent $*$-weakly, i.e. pointwise, then by the uniform boundedness principle the norms of $B_k$ are bounded. This implies that $A$ is bounded, equivalently continuous.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I see, you are totally right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not true for sequences. It is true however if you allow for nets, and the construction works abstractly (i.e. you can replace $L^1(S,\mu)$ by an arbitrary normed space).

For a finite-dimensional subspace $F$ of $L^1(S,\mu)$ the restriction $A|_F$ is continuous. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $A|_F$ can be extended to a continuous linear functional $B_F\in L^1(S,\mu)^\ast$. The finite-dimensional subspaces of $L^1(S,\mu)$ form a directed set ordered by inclusion, hence we get a net $(B_F)$.

If $f\in L^1(S,\mu)$, then $B_F(f)=A(f)$ whenever $f\in F$ by the construction of $B_F$. Thus $B_F(f)\to A(f)$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting. In asking the initial question I had mad an error in assuming the convergence was for all $f$ in the space. What I was thinking about is the following. When $A$ is the inverse of a compact linear operator it can be regularized (i.e., it is the point-wise limit of a sequence of bounded linear operators), but then  convergence will only hold for $f$ in the domain of $A$. I was wondering whether regularization schemes exist in some abstract sense for other unbounded operators.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're after. There is the uninteresting answer that every discontinuous linear functional on a normed space has a dense kernel, hence it can certainly be approximated by a sequence of continuous linear functionals on a dense subspace (namely the zero functional). But I guess that's not what you're thinking about.